# Up to what frequency is it practical to make my own filter?

Tags: rf, filter

I have some experimental radio systems.  One needs a filter, and it's hard to find at its frequency, at a reasonable cost.  Up to what frequency is it practical to use my own (eg. capacitor/inductor) filters?

Comment: If you have an SA, it can be practical into lots of GHz, if you don't have one, its unlikely to be practical anywhere

Comment: A filter is only limited by your experience and test equipment. 1st define the requirements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That depends on your knowledge, skills, equipment (to check if the filter works as intended) and also what type and components you'd to make a filter.

For active filters maybe you can push these up to 10 MHz perhaps. Not tried that myself yet.

For discrete RLC filters I'd say up you can also go up to 10 MHz.

You can push that to maybe 100 MHz if you also have a signal generator and an Oscilloscope (both up to 100 MHz obviously) to check the filter you build and compensate for parasitics.

Beyond that 100 MHz you really need a spectrum analyzer with tracking generator or a signal generator. A network analyzer would be even better but they are expensive.

Above 100 MHz you could consider microstrip type filters, these are special patterns on a PCB. It's work for an RF guru to design these (in an EM simulator).

Comment: I suspect that with a basic knowledge of microstrip/transmission line theory, one could get simple transmission line stuff (quarter wave stub notches and the like) done by hand.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Yes of course ! Most simple things should be learned (at least trying it out) by hand. That greatly enhances one's understanding of the design. The best designers design "by hand" and then only **check in the simulator** that what they drew is **correct**.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the system which you are attempting to work within can be used to evaluate the filter, up to a few GHz should be feasible - so long as you can control the parasitics well enough. Depends on the type of accuracy you need.